# Trigger before insert is not working

Tags: mysql, database

There is a "session" table, for it you need to write a trigger to check the date and time before inserting the data, if the date and time are greater than or equal to the current date and time, the value can be inserted into the table, otherwise the error message is displayed.

```
CREATE TABLE `seance` (
`idSeance` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Date/time` datetime NOT NULL,
`Hall_idHall` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Hall_Theatre_idTheatre` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Performance_idPerformance` int(45) NOT NULL,
`price` int(100) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TRIGGER `insert_seance` BEFORE INSERT ON `seance`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.`Date/time` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      THEN
        INSERT INTO seance
          (`idSeance`, `Date/time`, `Hall_idHall`, 
             `Hall_Theatre_idTheatre`,`Performance_idPerformance`, `price`) 
               VALUES (NEW.`idSeance`,NEW.`Date/time`,NEW.`Hall_idHall`,        
  NEW.`Hall_Theatre_idTheatre`,NEW.`Performance_idPerformance`,NEW.`price`);
                ELSE
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error for updating values';
                
      END IF;
 END
```

I can not understand why it gives an error?

## 1442 - Can't update table 'seance' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of few mysql error messages which are crystal clear (IMHO). However - You don't need that INSERT statement. Just rise an error if the data is invalid. If the data is valid, you don't need to do anything in the trigger. The row will be just inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_seance` BEFORE INSERT ON `seance` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`Date/time` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error for updating values';
    END IF;
END
```